# RewriteCond error with -f condition

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect all request to my website to the folder 'site' if the file exists in this folder.

E.g.: if my website contains the files /foo/foo.html, /bar/bar.html and /site/site.html
I'd want the following redirections:

```
/foo/foo.html -> /foo/foo.html
/bar/bar.html -> /bar/bar.html
/site/site.html -> /site/site.html
/site.html -> /site/site.html
```

I thought something like this should do the trick:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Check if the requested path is not a real file or folder
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
# if not a real file/folder: myhost.com/blabla -> myhost.com/site/blabla
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I get these errors in the log:

```
[warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.
```

Any idea what could be wrong ? I didn't get much from google on this error...

P.s.: I use a bluehost website and mod_rewrite is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you need all unknown requests to goto site.html you should use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/site.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I want the redirection to go to the folder site, not specifically site/site.html, so the first one should work.
I got plenty of "[warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.". And got an error on the number of redirect with a resulting url similar to this: http://mysite/site/site/site/site/site/site/site/site/site.html. I thought the L was supposed to stop the future rewritting ?
That's why I did the opposite in my example, testing if the file site/site.html exists before trying to redirect to it.

Comment: The problem came from Options +FollowSymLinks which isn't supported on my server... I use SymLinksIfOwnerMatch instead and it works with my code and yours without loop. Thanks !